# problem about script on python3.x ModuleNOtFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I've made a cli scrip in python.

when i write :

```
verbe-irregulier
```

it says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Timecraft122\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\verbe-irregulier.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'verbe_irregulier'
```

github repository of my project :
[text](https://github.com/Timecraft122/Verbe-irregulier)

Why it doesn't work ?

I'm french.